# Possible to make an Installation version of Blender with all current Add-ons and Settings?

Tags: windows, installation

Blender can be downloaded in a portable version, that doesn't need an installation. 
It's also possible to pack external data like models and textures into a .blendfile.

This makes me feel, it should be possible to pack my current Blender Version with all it's settings and all add-ons installed into such a version. 
I want to install it on a second machine but don't want to spend hours making sure every add-on and setting I accumulated over the years is the same.

Comment: For starters, what is your OS again?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole process is pretty easy and (in parts) also serves as a backup solution.

**Windows 7/8.x/10**

Open the Windows Explorer and copy/type "%AppData%" into the address bar.

[image: %AppData% in Windows Explorer address bar]

There you will find a folder named "Blender Foundation" which contains all the settings for Blender for all the versions you ever used on the computer. Copy this folder.

The second part would be the actual Software with all the add-ons. Open the Windows Explorer and copy/type "%ProgramFiles%" into the address bar.

There you will find a folder named "Blender Foundation" with all the Blender versions you have currently installed on your Computer. Copy this folder.

Since this is effectively a backup of everything you need to move Blender and its settings to a different machine, you can zip these folders and then just have to remember where to copy them on your new machine.

You can copy the "Blender Foundation" folder from "%ProgramFiles%" either back into the same folder on your new computer, or you just drop it where ever you find it fit and use the zipped version in the future.

Comment: If you use Linux, you might find the directory with the installed version subdirectories here:  /usr/share/blender